# Cursor object structure in android memory

Tags: android, android-sqlite

How does SQLite returns query results in android, I mean does android stores databases in RAM in device, if yes then what is the use of Cursor object(does it copies the result of query into a Cursor object and then return reference to it)?

Comment: see what is a base class of SQLiteCursor, it will explain much of your concerns